# Java persistence with sql server - cannot insert a row but it works well with mysql, why? Complains that table already exists

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, eclipselink

Here is my code:

```
package sqlserver;

import it.bsec.target.entity.Colore;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Failed to register the driver.");
        }

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306;" +
                   "databaseName=target;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String s = "use target";
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Colori";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                int id  = rs.getInt("Id");
                String desc = rs.getString("Descrizione");
                System.out.println(id + " : " + desc);
            }

            System.setProperty("eclipselink.target-database", "SqlServer");
            System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getProperty("jdbc.url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306;databaseName=target;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"));
            EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TARGET", System.getProperties());
            EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

            Colore c = new Colore();
            c.setId(6);
            c.setDescrizione("WHITE");
            entityManager.persist(c);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This query results in insertion of a new row into a table Colori in MySQL. When I run this example from within Eclipse with SQL Server, this is what I get (and insertion fails):

```
1 : BLUE
2 : GREY
3 : GREEN
4 : RED
5 : YELLOW
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'Colori' in the database.
Error Code: 2714
Call: CREATE TABLE dbo.Colori (Id INTEGER NOT NULL, Descrizione VARCHAR(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Id))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE dbo.Colori (Id INTEGER NOT NULL, Descrizione VARCHAR(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Id))")
```

But it is enough to modify this code slightly like so:

```
package sqlserver;

import it.bsec.target.entity.Colore;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("Failed to register the driver.");
        }

        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306;" +
                   "databaseName=target;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;";
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String s = "use target";
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Colori";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()) {
                int id  = rs.getInt("Id");
                String desc = rs.getString("Descrizione");
                System.out.println(id + " : " + desc);
            }

            System.setProperty("eclipselink.target-database", "SqlServer");
            System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            System.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getProperty("jdbc.url", "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:3306;databaseName=target;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"));
            EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TARGET", System.getProperties());
            EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            entityManager.createNativeQuery("insert into dbo.Colori(Id, Descrizione) values ('6', 'WHITE')").executeUpdate();
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.persist(c);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is an error I still get:

```
1 : BLUE
2 : GREY
3 : GREEN
4 : RED
5 : YELLOW
[EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'Colori' in the database.
Error Code: 2714
Call: CREATE TABLE dbo.Colori (Id INTEGER NOT NULL, Descrizione VARCHAR(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Id))
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE dbo.Colori (Id INTEGER NOT NULL, Descrizione VARCHAR(255) NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Id))")
```

HOWEVER, THIS TIME INSERTION SUCCEEDS (despite an error)! Does anyone understand why is it so and what am I doing wrong? In particular, why do I get error saying basically that table exists?? Of course it exists, it supposed to, no? How else could I try to insert anything into non existent table? How this can be an error?

I am using slqjdbc4 driver, eclipse link, java 6 EE persistence framework and below, I include code of my Entity Bean:

```
package it.bsec.target.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="dbo.Colori")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Colore implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Descrizione", length = 255)
    private String descrizione;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

}
```

Is just SQLServer not compatible with java persistence framework? I know it sounds strange, but what else can be the reason? Sorry, but I clearly don't know what is going wrong. Needless to say, the above query works perfectly when executed from within SQL Server Management Studio.

---

EDIT:
As suggested by Jens, I have added property eclipselink.ddl-generation and set its value to update, easy fix - now it does work with native queries, however when try an example with where I am trying persist an Entity Bean, it still fails (No error this time!) but it doesn't add any new row into the table. Any one knows what am I still missing and where would be a good source of information for this type of things, that I could learn from?
Thanks.

Comment: See the error message : `There is already an object named 'Colori' in the database` You try to create a table that is already existant

Comment: Sure Jens, I see, but how am I trying to create a table by inserting a row??? Especially the same query works with MySQL. What is the difference with SQL Server then? Especially in the second instance of Native query, where clearly I am not creating a new table, right, but only inserting a new row "insert into..."? Thanks for comment, I will appreciate clarification even more.

Comment: It will be done by JPA. try to add the property `eclipselink.ddl-generation` and set the value to `update`.

Comment: OH! I will do that, thanks! And will post an update. Stupid of me if that is the reason.

Comment: Partialy, that's that! Thanks, however - IT WORKS ONLY WITH NATIVE QUERY now, when I try to persist an entity it doesn't show any error now but it fails to add a row to a table, do You know why Jens? And where can I find information on all these properties I supposed to set, like the one you told me? If you want to post your comment as a response, I will gladly accept it :)! Thanks.

Comment: do you have an error message. Read [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.html) for properties. Have added the comment as answer

Comment: Thanks! I will accept it but before just need to solve that :) And thank you. No. I have no error message, because there is no error being shown - it just doesn't insert a new row... :( By the way - link is dead - but I see the point, it points me to Eclipse site.

Comment: Sorry my fault: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm

Comment: Nice, do you know what about that entity persistence? It just can't get persisted. Your answer works for native queries but still can't persist entity - no error being shown.

Comment: Try to call `entityManager.flush();` after `persist(c)`

Comment: I did - that causes an error, telling me that there is no active transaction. I haven't had to start and close transactions with MySQL to call entityManager.persist(entity), does that mean I need to do that with SQL Server? If I do it in within transaction - it works, but I didn't have to do that this way (within explicit transaction: between entityManager.getTransaction().begin() and entityManager.getTransaction().commit) with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be done by JPA. try to add the property `eclipselink.ddl-generation` and set the value to `update`

```
      System.setProperty("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "update");
```

Comment: I did use entityManager.flush() as suggested by you - that causes an error, telling me that there is no active transaction. I haven't had to start and close transactions with MySQL to call entityManager.persist(entity), does that mean I need to do that with SQL Server? If I do it in within transaction - it works, but I didn't have to do that this way (within explicit transaction: between entityManager.getTransaction().begin() and entityManager.getTransaction().commit) with MySQL

Comment: @Pawel: sorry can't get you!

Comment: No worries, I think I got it. My fault - your answer was perfect. :)